# entity detection - entities clashing with english words

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, azure-language-understanding, named-entity-extraction

I have few sentences like below

- `what is the sales org for fpc 1234 for IS?`
- `give me sales org for fpc 12234 for IS?`
- `give me sales org for fpc 12234 with scope ME?`

In the above sentences, the entity I'm looking for is `IS`, `IS` and `ME` respectively. These entities include, `IS`, `ME`, `AN`, `AM` which are common while constructing a sentence in English. I'm using `LUIS` for entity detection and maintaining the entities as a list entity. The issue is that, though `LUIS` is able to detect the entities (`IS`,`AN`,`AM`) its detecting them on the normal sentences like

- `what is the sales org for fpc 1234`

In the above sentence, we do not have any entity but the entity `IS` is picked up.

How do we detect the entities only if they're addressed actually and not a part of sentence construction.

Few points to note:

- The list of entities is really long to train the entities rather than use entities
- We can't hard code to find the occurrence of a entity twice as it may fail like here:

  - `give me sales org for fpc 12234 for IS?`
  - `ME,IS` do not occur twice and cannot be used to create a rule.
- The issue is not with `LUIS` but entity extraction in general. I'm looking at `POS` tagging as well but that needs the entity to be present in capital letter to identify it as a Noun, which may not be the case always.

  - Also have just tried out the POS tagging using Spacy. Below are the results.
  - which sales org extended to the fpc 1234 for TO? - TO is classified as preposition (which it is actually.)
    [image]
  - what is the sales org for fpc 1234 with scope IS? - IS is classified as a Verb
    [image]

Comment: Is this NLP for a chat bot or something else?

Comment: Yes this is for a chatbot !

Comment: Are you hoping to have LUIS identify the entities correctly by considering capitalization or just from the grammatical context in the sentence? As I understand it, LUIS ignores capitalization.

Comment: LUIS does identify the entities now, but, the catch is that they're list entities and LUIS does an exact match. It would be good if LUIS can identify the entity from grammatical context. Yes, also as you said, LUIS ignores the capitalization. We can process the question in the backend to understand the entity but I'm looking for a proper approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably figured out that [non-machine-learned entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-entity-types#non-machine-learned-entities-dont-use-context) are not ideal in your case because they don't take context into consideration. I think you have a few options.

### Option 1: Simple Entities

I just tested by adding your three utterances to an intent named "Sales org" and then creating a [simple entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-entity-types#simple-entity) named "Scope." I labeled IS, IS, and ME at the ends of those utterances as the Scope entity. LUIS was then able to correctly identify "is" as the entity but not "me" when I tested "give me sales org for fpc 12234 for is?"

After making a call to LUIS, your bot code can then validate the recognized entity to make sure it's within the list of acceptable values.

### Option 2: Roles

If you still want to use a list entity, you can still have LUIS give you [contextual information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-entity-types#context-with-non-machine-learned-entities) about the entity by using [roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-roles).

I just tested by creating an entity named "ScopeName" with your four values IS, ME, AN, and AM. I then created two roles for that entity: "scope" and "falsePositive." Then I labeled the entities in the "Sales org" utterances like this:

[image]

If you do this, LUIS will still recognize IS, ME, AN, and AM when they're in the parts of the sentence where you don't want them to be recognized, but you'll know to ignore them in your bot code because they'll be assigned the "falsePositive" role.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle Delaney. This is what I did. The entities had to be machine learned ones. We tried to pile up as many samples as possible and were able to get a good performance now. Also thanks for the suggestion on roles. I'll need to give that a try. Accepting the answer :)

Comment: What I exactly did was, I've created new Simple entity and trained the utterance labelled with the new entity say 'scope'. I then made use of the existing list entity to compare if the values received from the list entity is matching value received from the new scope entity. If yes, go forward. If no, ask the user for the scope input again. As we move forward with the use case to testing and then production, we hope we'll have more variations of the utterances to train and less failures.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, a correct parse of the sentence will give you PoS tags which will help you get the right answers. Unfortunately, the examples you show have poor grammar, so even the best parsers may struggle.

Do you have enough curated data to train a neural net? An LSTM might manage to learn enough about the grammar actually used in these sentences to do the NER successfully.

In the examples you give, the names to find are all a single token. If that is typical, it will make the job easier.

The comment below says that there is not enough data to train a neural net. The few examples given are very stereotyped. Is it possible to train a Naive Bayes classifier using previous and next token as the predictors?

Comment: Yes @chrishmorris. The names we need to identify are always single tokens. But the problem is that we do not have enough data to train a neural net. We were thinking of using spacy's NER by training with whatever samples we currently, but I doubt its efficiency given the single token that needs to be extracted.